# SAXParseException: The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" is not bound

Tags: java, xml, web-services, wsdl, websphere

I'm getting the error when I try to call WebService (HP-Service Manager, if it's going to help) from the class deployed to **WebSphere 7.0.** The same code functions when I call it from JUnit code...

The fragment of WSDL is:

```
<definitions targetNamespace="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7"
xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
```

I've thought that the `xmlns:xsi` is always knows to the XML parser, so I don't understand that error. Why such error occures on WebSphere, while it does not occur when code is launched in JUnit using `com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient`?

The adequate StackTrace fragment is:

> Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException:
>   faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing
>   'wsjar:file:/path/to/ear.ear/war.war/WEB-INF/lib/my_jar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/wsdl/myWsdl.wsdl'.:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Das Präfix "xsi" für Attribut
>   "xsi:schemaLocation", das einem Elementtyp "definitions" zugeordnet
>   ist, ist nicht gebunden.
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2255)
>     at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2330)
>     at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2296)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper$13.run(WSDL4JWrapper.java:745)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.loadDefinition(WSDL4JWrapper.java:742)
>     ... 51 more Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Das Präfix
>   "xsi" für Attribut "xsi:schemaLocation", das einem Elementtyp
>   "definitions" zugeordnet ist, ist nicht gebunden.     at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2245)
>     ... 56 more

Comment: try including this in the definition tag xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" also check this https://community.jboss.org/message/329336

Comment: it was not complete tag definition, the xmlns is present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error probably stems not from the WSDL but from the XML sent back from the WebService. You may want to get a glance at what XML exactly is returned and check if the `xsi` namespace is bound correctly in the document.

Apart from that, it may well be a minor difference in configuration of each parser instance (server vs. JUnit) which causes one parser to reject the unbound namespace and the other one to just ignore this "glitch" in the XML parsed. (See for instance [setNamespaces()](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/xerces/framework/XMLParser.html#setNamespaces%28boolean%29) for the apache parser.)

Comment: Oops. Missed that part of the error message :o) Just read "error when I try to call WebService", so I assumed the error comes from the *call* itself.

Comment: The part of your WSDL seems to validate just fine. - Are you sure you are using the *same* WSDL file locally and on the server?

Comment: Yes, this is stacktrace from server, and it is reading from jar file (only path and names are anonymised)

Comment: I seem to understand that, however I assume you don't access the same *file* from the same *JAR* that is deployed on the server in your JUnit tests. Maybe you have different versions of that file deployed on the server and in your unit test setup respectively?

Comment: No, I have only 1 version of it, with 1 difference, I have changed the xsd filename from lowercase to camelcase because it was so referenced in WSDL. But in JUnit that was ignored, so I think that the other version of DocumentFactory/SaxParser/whatever is used, but in closed-source technologies it's really difficult to say what where happens

Comment: Actually, it was an error caused by Eclipse, which didn't write the camel-case edit to the filesystem, which resulted in difference between IBM-RAD build and maven build

Answer (score 3):

The error means exactly what it says: there is no namespace declaration for the xsi prefix.

It's not true that XML parsers have built-in knowledge of this namespace. It needs to be declared to make the document namespace-well-formed.

Comment: Yet, in the OP's XML snippet the `xsi` prefix actually *is* bound: "xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" ...